# Mongo errors that type needs to be array

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

I'm trying to update push some data into a document in mongodb. The following runs fine:

```
import pymongo
import bson
from bson.objectid import ObjectId

client = pymongo.MongoClient('mongodb://localhost:27351/')
db = client.db
foo = db.foo

for i in range(2):
    nm = "xxx"+str(i)
    foo.insert_one({
            "foo":"bar", 
            "name": nm, 
            "friends": i, 
            "enemies": i+10, 
            "relations":
            {
                "friends": i,
                "enemies": i+10
            }
        })
```

I can then add to one of the ducuments like so:

```
foo.update_one({"name": "xxx1"},{"$push":{"comment":{"initial": "hello", "last": "world"}}})
list(foo.find())
```

It returns this:

```
[{'_id': ObjectId('575f3b32f203c6069d9674ee'),
  'enemies': 10,
  'foo': 'bar',
  'friends': 0,
  'name': 'xxx0',
  'relations': {'enemies': 10, 'friends': 0}},
 {'_id': ObjectId('575f3b32f203c6069d9674ef'),
  'comment': [{'initial': 'hello', 'last': 'world'}],
  'enemies': 11,
  'foo': 'bar',
  'friends': 1,
  'name': 'xxx1',
  'relations': {'enemies': 11, 'friends': 1}}]
```

The problem is the following that errors - why?:

```
foo.update_one({"name": "xxx1"},{"$push":{"relations":{"enemies": 99, "friends": 88}}})
```

> WriteError: The field 'relations' must be an array but is of type
>   Object in document {_id: ObjectId('575f3b32f203c6069d9674ef')}

Comment: You can't `$push` onto an object, only an array.  You probably want `$set` instead.

Comment: @BadZen I'd like to add the new dict to the atribute `"relations"`, so not adjust the existing dict that is relations but add a new dict to it .. so it becomes a collection of dicts

Comment: "not to adjust <X>... but add a new dict to <X>".  What?   If you want to add a named field to an Object, use `$set`.   If you want to have an array of objects, use an Array, not an Object.   Currently your 'relations' field is an Object, not an Array.   (It could for example be 'relations': [{'enemies': 10, 'friends': 0}], then you could push a new object onto it.)

Comment: nitpick:  'dict' is the Python type.   The mongodb type is Object.   They're... different.

Comment: You can't push into object. What your document should look like after the update operation?